# call multiple subroutines from inside FOR in batch

Tags: windows, batch-processing

I made that kind of a script:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%C in (list.txt) DO (
    call :func1 %%C
    if /i %var1%==true call :func2 %%C
    if %var2%==true call :func3 %%C
)
goto:eof

:func1
some routine
goto:eof

:func2
some routine
goto:eof

:func3
some routine
goto:eof
```

var1 and var2 are set inside func1 and func2.
But i only get this:

```
C:\>samplebatch.bat
call was unexpected at this time.
```

And it does not depend on what I put in those functions. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%var1%` doesn't have a new value because you aren't using delayed expansion.

If `var1` had a value before the for loop started then it would still have the same value.

Comment: That really helped, thanks a lot! For some reason I decided that "set" outside FOR itself will work without delayed extension %)

Answer (score 0):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, if `var1` is not set then batch will interpret `if /i %var1%==true call :func2 %%C` as `if /i ==true call :func2 %%C`.

Since `call` is not a comparison-operator that `cmd` expects, you get the error you report.

The easy way to fix this is

```
set "var1="
for /F "tokens=*" %%C in (list.txt) DO (
    call :func1 %%C
    if defined var1 call :func2 %%C
)
```

where `if defined` interprets the run-time status of the variable - whether or not it is defined, so if `func1` defines `var1` then the `call func2` will be executed; if `func1` clears `var1` then `call func2` will not be executed.